# How to keep showing a div if the validation fails?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, struts2

I have a web application using `Struts2` in which I am validating a form for the name and email address. I am validating name using plain `javascript` easy enough but for the email address I am calling a service. So I have a method in jsp which does the validation for the name and also submits the form for the email validation.

These text fields are in a div tag and it hides once everything is fine but in case of invalid name this div tag doesn't hide because it prompts the user with the message to provide name.In case of email address I want the same behavior (want to show the email message) without hiding the div tag but I am not sure how to do it?

JSP

```
<form name="resendEsignatureFormId" id="resendEsignatureFormId" action="<integration:urlAction actionName='myAction' method="POST"/>

function validateEmailAddress() {       
    if( document.getElementById( 'nameId' ).value == "" ) {
        document.getElementById( 'display' ).innerHTML ='Please provide name';
        return false;
    }   
    document.getElementById( 'resendEsignatureFormId' ).submit();
}   

<div id="Signers" style="display: none;">
        <s:iterator value="intgDetails.custDetails.signers" var="signerslist">
            <div class="sectionHeaderLine"></div>
            <div class="sectionHeader">Signer #<%=ct%></div>
            <!-- <div id="display" class="fieldLabelBold" style="color:#0033CC"></div> -->
            <div id="display" class="fieldLabelBold" style="color:red"> 
                <c:if test="${emailValidationMessage != null}">
                    <div class="fieldLabelBold" style="color:red">${emailValidationMessage}</div>
                </c:if>
            </div>
            <table width=100%>                                              
                <tr align="left">
                    <td align="left">
                        <s:textfield name="nameId" id="nameId" label="Name" cssClass="dataFieldCell3" value="%{#signerslist.name}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr align="left">
                    <td align="left">
                        <s:textfield name="emailId" id="emailId" label="Email" cssClass="dataFieldCell3" value="%{#signerslist.email}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <s:textfield name="recipientId" id="recipientId" style="display: none;" value="%{#signerslist.recipientId}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%
                    ct++;
                %>
            </table>
        </s:iterator>

        <table width=100%>
            <tr>
                <td class="esignNavigation">            
                    <a href="#x" onclick ="return validateEmailAddress()"><span>Confirm</span></a>
                    <a href="#x" onclick="hideSigners()"><span>Cancel</span></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: If everything is not fine then it doesn't show.

Comment: Meaning if the validation fails, I want to show the message that "Invalid Email Address" instead of hiding the div.

Comment: At first, you create them in an iterator so you'll have several tags with same id which breaks! Secondly, where is your form? What is it's action result ? same page as above?